# iPhone: Merge 2 mp3 files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mp3

Can some body explain how we can merge 2 mp3 files on iPhone? is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean 'merge' - overlay, or join?

Comment: Merge means if i have two MP3 files fisrt is for 30 sec and second is for 20 sec. After merge there should be single file and as i play after it will be of 50 sec. first it will play 30 sec then 20 Sec(Singlle MP3) file.

Comment: Kamleshwar!
I have exactly task as you have. Did you find your decision?
Best regards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [merge Audio files on iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359313/merge-audio-files-on-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, it is for concatenation not for mixing.
Haven't tested myself, but I will soon

```
NSMutableData *part1=[NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"part1" ofType: @"mp3"]];
NSMutableData *part2=[NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"part2" ofType: @"mp3"]];

[part1 appendData: part2];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *mp3file = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"test.mp3"];

[part1 writeToFile: mp3file atomically:YES];
```

I think it should work

Comment: It doesn't. The result is the first mp3, only larger in size.