# Is it possible to combine 4 sound track in Single track?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [merge Audio files on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359313/merge-audio-files-on-iphone)

I want to combine 4 sound records together. 
My app record sound tracks one by one . After finish with recording, i have to combine those recorded tracks in single sound track for play and share.

Is it can be done with the help of AVAssetWriter.

Comment: One sound after the other (concat)? or the four sounds at the same time (mix)?

Comment: Four sounds at same time